# Why isn't Skype appearing under Settings > Privacy?

Tags: skype

[image]

I use only Desktop version of Skype. After Skype updated itself to 8.44.0.40 several days ago, others can hear me but I can’t hear them. Reinstalling Skype didn't help. My microphone and speakers are functioning perfectly for other programs. As beneath, Skype acknowledges my microphone and voice.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eyfo.jpg)

Comment: @Ramhound Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will not appear in the Microphone privacy list. only UWP apps (Apps from the Microsoft Store) will appear in the list.

You may need to check Skype's [Audio and Video settings](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34863/how-do-i-change-audio-and-video-settings-in-skype-on-desktop) to ensure it is set to use the correct device, and that other settings are correct.

You can also check sound settings by right clicking the speaker by your clock and choosing "Sounds" to open the sound settings applet, and ensure those devices are set correctly there.

If you don't see your microphone listed, you may need to update your drivers.